# Android Material Design

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, material-design

Does the new Android Material Design support old version of android such as 3.0 or 2.1? if it supports how would it look like? as a real material design or just as old design? I am about to update my app with material design theme so is there anybody who already has done this?

Comment: "Does the new Android Material Design will support old version of android such as 3.0 or 2.1?" -- AFAIK, there is no production support for Material Design on Android today. The "L" Developer Preview has some aspects of Material Design, for use on "L" only. "I am about to update my app with material design theme so is there anybody who already done this?" -- I suggest that you hold off on this for a few months, until the next version of Android ships, with an update to the Android Support package, and then see what is available for older APIs.

Comment: I came to this decision because evernote has updated with kinda material design. i was wondering how did those guys do with new design without proper support from android. because new evernote runs on API18

Comment: It's possible that Evernote is working closely with Google engineers, with pre-release versions of updated Android Support packages and the like. Or, it's possible that Evernote is "jumping the gun" and will wind up redoing things someday to better match a "real" Material Design implementation that comes out in the upcoming months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as material design as a concept goes, yes you can do it all today. Some aspects of it would require a lot more work on your part (for example, imitating the new action bar design guidelines), whereas some parts are a lot more simple (e.g. the new guidelines for content spacing and colors).

There are also some libraries available to help you with this. There are many third party libraries out there that support the concept of "cards" such as [Cards UI for Android](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android) and [Cardslilb](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib), and there is a library for the [Floating Action Button](https://github.com/FaizMalkani/FloatingActionButton).

As far as the Material theme goes for more or less automatically making your app "Material," no, there is no support library implementation available right now. What you see on the market at the moment is mostly done from scratch. I recommended holding off until Android L is officially released. The new versions of the support libraries will include support for at least some of this functionality ([such as `CardView`](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Why there is a big fuzz about card design instead of just a plain ListView. and what happened to the GridView list a sticker design?

Comment: Card design is becoming big because Google has started including it in most if its apps, and it is a very high visibility element of Material design. Google provides some guidance on when to use a card list vs. a normal list vs. a grid [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-usage) and [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v7 Appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) and the [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) to support Material design on pre-Lollipop Android versions.